# Where can I find a photo browser or carousel control for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, controls

Are there any good image, photo browser or carousel controls for Delphi?

I would prefer something free if available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not free, but [TMS Software GUI Motions](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/guimotions.asp) seems to be quite stunning:
[image: TMS Software GUI Motions]

Comment: Gui Motions looks great and is easy to use. There are a couple of problems, firstly it requires reasonable graphics grunt, on a low end laptop with a poor graphics card it is slow and jerky. Also I have found it a little unreliable, it's a little hit and miss whether it will work on a customers laptop.  Generally TMS components are fantastic in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

[PicShow Components](http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/picshow/) at Delphi Area looks like it will do what you want. I haven't tried it myself, only remembered it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search yields some results that may suit your needs:

[Some Planet Source code contributions](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/BrowseCategoryOrSearchResults.asp?txtCriteria=image+viewer&blnWorldDropDownUsed=TRUE&txtMaxNumberOfEntriesPerPage=10&blnResetAllVariables=TRUE&lngWId=7&B1=Quick+Search&optSort=Alphabetical)

[Wilsons Image Viewer (Delphi 5 I believe)](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d6imageviewer.htm)

although some of the code may be dated, the examples can set you on the right track and give you a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a good one. But seems its no longer updated :(

[GLScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net/wikka/GlsceneDownloads)

But its exactly what I need and free.

Ok TMS Software GUI Motions it much better. And I think I will buy it but for now this one will do fine …

Comment: GLScene is a little off from what you asked for, though... But if you can use it, everything is nice :-)